# Meaning of には in this sentence.

Tags: grammar

> ……こういう時の遠坂**には**どんなワガママもし放題なのであるが、生憎、ここはちょっとの油断で轢き飛ばされる制限速度六十キロ車道、二車線である。

When Tohsaka is like this she does anything she wants but, sadly, this is a a 2 lane traffic road with a limit of 60 km/h where you can be sent flying if you are not careful.

Is this correct?

Or this に is にたいして

> ……こういう時の遠坂**にたいして**どんなワガママもし放題なのであるが、生憎、ここはちょっとの油断で轢き飛ばされる制限速度六十キロ車道、二車線である。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

に denotes the target (of your arrogant request) and は is a topic marker, without which the sentence would sound like inversion of "どんなワガママもし放題なのは、こういう時の遠坂にであるが".

As your translation, it's fine, and yes, that に is the same as に対して (though you somehow have cut off は).

Comment: So the one who does whatever she wants is Tohsaka or the speaker?

Comment: It's the speaker who can do whatever s/he wants.